# What to do with the [cdr] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr) tag refers to the operation used in the Lisp family of languages but it's apparently also used to refer to the [call detail records](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/database_storing-cdr.html) (CDR) format used in the open source [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) software.

There are currently 62 questions with the tag, with a distribution of about ~30 related to Lisp, ~30 related to Asterisk and a few question relating to the file format used in the Corel Draw graphics software.

Since **cdr** has been associated with Lisp since the the late '50s and there exists a corresponding [cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cons) tag it would seem correct to either remove the [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr) tag from questions not relating to Lisp, or to change it to something like [asterisk-cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asterisk-cdr) (my proposal).

The questions relating to Corel Draw could be retagged as just [coreldraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coreldraw).

Maybe there are too few questions to bother though, I'm not sure about the proper procedure here.

Edit: apparently as pointed out by ComputerDruid **cdr** isn't specific to Asterisk, and so it would make more sense to remove it from the Lisp questions and re-purpose the tag and tag wiki to fit the new use.

Comment: Is the CDR format unique to Asterisk?  If so, I would say just burn that particular usage.

Comment: what about compact disc-recordable?

Comment: @jpw i was just kidding

Answer (score 11):

CDR is not an asterisk-specific term (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record ), so [asterisk-cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asterisk-cdr) would not be a very good name for the proposed tag.

Given that there's no corresponding [car](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/car) for [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr), I don't think it makes sense to have a tag for the `cdr` function in lisp.

I would propose keeping [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr) for call-details-record, and untag the lisp-related uses, but this goes against the current [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr) tag wiki.

Comment: Good point; I assumed it was specific to Asterisk and didn't research it further. Removing it from the Lisp related questions and changing the tag wiki seems more reasonable in light of this. I don't know the proper procedure to change an existing tag and wiki though.

Comment: Given the fact the wiki says Lisp, and that half the questions are Lisp, and that the Lisp meaning is cannonical for the command name and older I think the one to be renamed should be the phone one.  Maybe to calldetailrecord

Comment: Possibly rename both? `call-detail-record` and `lisp-cdr`?

Comment: lisp usage may be canonical but it's also worthless. get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

Even though there is some Lisp usage of [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr), it isn't useful. It should be untagged from all Lisp-related questions.

There needs to be a new tag for the call detail record, Naming it [calldetailrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calldetailrecord) would make it harder for people to mistake for something else, although I'm sure someone will manage it. If the tag keeps the name [cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdr) then people will continue using it for the Lisp function. Almost nobody reads the info on the tag.

What will undoubtedly happen is that someone will create a new tag for cdr and use it for Lisp questions. At least when they do that, if the calldetailrecord uses have all been retagged with the spelled-out name, then that tag won't get contaminated all over again.

[car](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/car) gets stuck on a lot of Lisp questions in spite of a clear warning stating to use it only for some R-specific thing. I found one question that used it for a beginner OO question involving modeling vehicles. [car](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/car) should get untagged from all questions that don't involve R.

Comment: While I totally agree with [tag:calldetailrecord] idea instead of CDR, it is far more clear, I don't see why 'car' with its whole 52 questions should stay reserved for R. Lisp has far longer history. although I have to admit R got its fame recently :) Anyways, since those CDRs and CARs are completely unrelated, I'd suggest [tag:lisp-car], [tag:lisp-cdr], [tag:r-car] and a [tag:telephony-cdr], the latter one as a synonym for [tag:calldetailrecord]. That way, when someone writes a question and enters "CDR" or "CAR" tag, he will see all options (lisp, R, telephony) and can choose apropriatelly.

Comment: uh, of course, **only if** there are some noticeable questions for lisp. In general I'm somewhat against putting function/command names in tags. "lisp" tag and proper post title should be enough in that case. What I wanted to say is [tag:r-car] and [tag:telephony-cdr] would probably be more clear than leaving easily misused short `cdr` and `car` tags.

Comment: I like the idea of having multiple tags to get a list of choices; but maybe the car/cdr doesn't fill much purpose in the context of Lisp anyway. To me the best action seems to be to introduce a r-car tag and a calldetailrecord tag and removing the car and cdr tags from all posts.